# Ошибка при подключении одного файла python в другой

Tags: python

У меня есть 2 файла: `first.py`, `second.py`.

В `first.py` написан следующий код:

```
def SumThis(a, b):
    return (a+b)
```

В `second.py` записано:

```
from first import *
a = 2
b = 3
print(SumThis(a,b))
```

В файле `second.py` ругается на подключение. Пишет:

> unresolved reference 'first'

Как это исправить, если оба файла находятся в одной директории?

Comment: Как вы запускаете second.py?

Comment: `cd папка_с_башими_файлами`, затем `python second.py` - работает без проблем.

Comment: Да, действительно. Всё работает без проблем, но PyCharm подчёркивает красным название _first_. Причём запускает и выдаёт верный результат как через консоль, так и через _run 'second.py'_. Из-за чего такое может происходить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first.py

```
from second import *

def func_first():
    a = 2
    b = 3
    print(func_second(a,b))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func_first()
```

second.py

```
def func_second(a, b):
    c = a + b
    return c
```